# Numba functions and pickle

Tags: python, numba

I'm having a problem using joblib to execute a recursive numba function in parallel. When using numba's jit on a recursive function and then trying to use joblib on that function, I get an error (reproduced at the end).

Any workarounds you can think of? The only I can think of is to re-write the function without recursion. 
I would normally report this on github, but I don't know whose problem it is, cloudpickly or numba. What do you think?

Thanks!

This code reproduces the problem:

```py
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
from numba import njit, int64

@njit(int64(int64))
def df(n):
    if n <= 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * df(n - 2)

Parallel(n_jobs=2, verbose=1)(delayed(df)(2)  for _ in range(2))
```

Error message (many lines at the beginning ignored)

```
  File "/home/.../anaconda3/envs/test_bug/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save                                       
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self                                                                          
  File "/home/.../anaconda3/envs/test_bug/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 856, in save_dict                                  
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())                                                                                              
  File "/home/.../anaconda3/envs/test_bug/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 882, in _batch_setitems                            
    save(v)                                                                                                                        
  File "/home/.../anaconda3/envs/test_bug/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 524, in save                                       
    rv = reduce(self.proto)                                                                                                        
  File "/home/.../anaconda3/envs/test_bug/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/dispatcher.py", line 585, in __reduce__         
    globs = self._compiler.get_globals_for_reduction()                                                                             
  File "/home/.../anaconda3/envs/test_bug/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/dispatcher.py", line 89, in get_globals_for_redu
ction                                                                                                                              
    return serialize._get_function_globals_for_reduction(self.py_func)                                                             
  File "/home/.../anaconda3/envs/test_bug/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/serialize.py", line 55, in _get_function_globals
_for_reduction                                                                                                                     
    func_id = bytecode.FunctionIdentity.from_function(func)                                                                        
  File "/home/.../anaconda3/envs/test_bug/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/bytecode.py", line 291, in from_function        
    func = get_function_object(pyfunc)
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded 



During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:                                                                

Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                 
  File "/home/.../anaconda3/envs/test_bug/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/backend/queues.py", line 151, in
 _feed                                                                                                                             
    obj, reducers=reducers)                                                                                                        
  File "/home/.../anaconda3/envs/test_bug/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/backend/reduction.py", line 145,
 in dumps                                                                                                                          
    p.dump(obj)                                                                                                                    
  File "/home/.../anaconda3/envs/test_bug/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 290, in __getstate__        
    for func, args, kwargs in self.items]                                                                                          
  File "/home/.../anaconda3/envs/test_bug/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 290, in <listcomp>          
    for func, args, kwargs in self.items]                                                                                          
  File "/home/.../anaconda3/envs/test_bug/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 278, in _wrap_non_picklable_
objects                                                                                                                            
    wrapped_obj = CloudpickledObjectWrapper(obj)                                                                                   
  File "/home/.../anaconda3/envs/test_bug/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 208, in __init__            
    self.pickled_obj = dumps(obj)                                                                                                  
  File "/home/.../anaconda3/envs/test_bug/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/externals/cloudpickle/cloudpickle.py", line 918
, in dumps                                                                                                                         
    cp.dump(obj)                                                                                                                   
  File "/home/.../anaconda3/envs/test_bug/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/externals/cloudpickle/cloudpickle.py", line 272
, in dump                                                                                                                          
    raise pickle.PicklingError(msg)                                                                                                
_pickle.PicklingError: Could not pickle object as excessively deep recursion required.                                             
"""                                                                                                                                

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:                                                               

Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                 
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>                                                                                              
  File "/home/.../anaconda3/envs/test_bug/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 996, in __call__            
    self.retrieve()                                                                                                                
  File "/home/.../anaconda3/envs/test_bug/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 899, in retrieve            
    self._output.extend(job.get(timeout=self.timeout))                                                                             
  File "/home/.../anaconda3/envs/test_bug/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 517, in wrap_futur
e_result                                                                                                                           
    return future.result(timeout=timeout)                                                                                          
  File "/home/.../anaconda3/envs/test_bug/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 432, in result                   
    return self.__get_result()                                                                                                     
  File "/home/.../anaconda3/envs/test_bug/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 384, in __get_result             
    raise self._exception                                                                                                          
_pickle.PicklingError: Could not pickle the task to send it to the workers
```

Comment: Seems more like a numba issue, also errors with builtin `pickle`

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug and will be fixed in Numba, https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/3370 (I guess in version 0.41)